# How to find the optimum split points for GBDT?

Tags: cart, algorithms, boosting

**GBDT (Gradient Boosting Decision Tree)** is an ensemble model of decision trees that are trained in sequence(i.e. an ensemble model of boosting). In each iteration, GBDT learns the decision tree by fitting the residual errors (errors upto the current iteration). This means every subsequent learner tries to learn the difference between actual output and the weighted sum of predictions until an iteration before. The errors are minimized using the gradient method.

*The costliest operation in GBDT is training the decision tree and the most time-consuming task is to find the optimum split points.*

> **What are the Split finding algorithms that are used to find optimum splits?**
>
> **How are the optimum split points created?**

Comment: You can read paper **Greedy Function Approximation: A Gradient Boosting Machine.**
and sklearn [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html)
> criterion{‘friedman_mse’, ‘mse’, ‘mae’}, default=’friedman_mse’